# Migrating from EventSender to PartitionSender - how to tell if sender is closed?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I am trying to migrate code that used the old EventHubSender from the Microsoft.ServiceBus (.Net Framework) to the new PartitionSender in the Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs package. In the old package I could run OnClosed on the sender and recreate it if needed. However, I can't find any way to do it here.

I have a "sender pool" that I am maintaining so I want to make sure that no one closed the sender before I pass it to some other call.

Any direction in this matter will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, Current version `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs 4.0.0` does not have this feature, but EventHub team is working on this, and will be released in the future version.

Click [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/7365) to see the progress.

Hope it helps.